# Woocommerce max 2 items in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a code that allows me to add a maximum of 1 item in cart.

```
/**
 * @snippet       WooCommerce Only one product in cart
 * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
 * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=560
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 3.3.4
 */

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'bbloomer_only_one_in_cart', 99, 2 );

function bbloomer_only_one_in_cart( $passed, $added_product_id ) {

global $woocommerce;

// empty cart: new item will replace previous
$woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

// display a message if you like
wc_add_notice( 'Product added to cart!', 'notice' );

return $passed;
}
```

I want to increase this amount to 2 items, i want it to work the exact same as this code, just with 2 items insteado 1. How do i do thi?

Comment: you can use WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() to get the number of items in your cart and if the count is 2 then run this code... but this will empty the cart 1st and then it will add the product..

Comment: try `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();` and check condition based on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below code :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'bbloomer_only_one_in_cart', 99, 2 );

function bbloomer_only_one_in_cart( $passed, $added_product_id ) {

global $woocommerce;

// empty cart: new item will replace previous
$_cartQty = count( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() );
if($_cartQty >= 2){
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();   
}

// display a message if you like
wc_add_notice( 'Product added to cart!', 'notice' );

return $passed;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to update the cart if the maximum is reached? if you have 2 and you add another 2 then update with the newest 2

Comment: Try with updated code

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working