# WooCommerce Another Way To Limit Maximum Cart Items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to limit the number of items a user can have in cart to a maximum of 1 item (regardless the quantity).

There are several answers about how to achieve this using 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation' & 'woocommerce_update_cart_validation' filters (e.g. [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46008534/746741), [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50948861), [answer 3](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-allow-1-product-cart/), ...).

It's also possible to use existing plugins like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-cart-limit/) one but it doesn't support maximum number of items limit.

However, in my case, both filters didn't fire due to the customization to 'Add to cart' logic that is done by the theme I'm using (for business/technical reasons that are irrelevant to discuss here).

That said, I need to achieve the same functionality using a different solution (using another filters, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the required functionality, this can be done by using 'woocommerce_add_cart_item' filter as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item' , 'validate_cart_max_items');

function validate_cart_max_items( $item_data ) {
  // Check total cart quantity
  $cart_contents_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

  // If quantity > 0, cancel current item addition to cart & display an error message
  if($cart_contents_count > 0) {
    $item_data = NULL;
    wc_add_notice( "A maximum of 1 item can be added to your cart", "error" );
  }

  return $item_data;
}
```

The above code snippet should be added to functions.php file under your active theme folder.

This code snippet has been tested using WordPress v5.3.1 and WooCommerce v3.8.1